# Having trouble making 3D wireframe with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a dataset that I am trying to bin into a matrix and then make a wireframe plot out of.  When I show the plot, all that shows is a flat surface along the x=y line of the 3d image.  I would like the full matrix to show.  I have included my code as well as a sample of the stats.txt:

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
f  = open('stats.txt')

bins = 10

xs = []
ys = []

for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split(' ')
        xs.append(float(line[0]))
        ys.append(float(line[1]))
xlin = linspace(min(xs),max(xs),bins+1)
ylin = linspace(min(ys),max(ys),bins+1)

matrix = zeros((bins,bins))

for i in range(bins):
        for j in range(bins):
                count = 0
                for s in range(len(xs)):
                        if xs[s] >= xlin[i] and xs[s] <= xlin[i+1] and ys[s] >= ylin[j] and ys[s] <= ylin[j+1]:
                                count +=1
                matrix[i,j] = count
print matrix

x = []
y = []
for i in range(bins):
        x.append([0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.])

for i in range(bins):
        y.append([0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.])
#for i in range(bins):
#       y.append(linspace(0,bins-1,bins))



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

print shape(x)
print shape(y)
print shape(matrix)
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, matrix)

#plt.imshow(matrix,cmap=plt.cm.ocean)
plt.show()
```

Sample of stats.txt:

```
10385.8694574 114.758131279
11379.8955938 -166.830995639
10347.5572407 165.168099188
11698.0834105 110.188708959
12100.3323331 185.316597413
11530.3943217 287.99795812
11452.2864796 474.890116234
12181.4426414 149.266756079
10962.8512477 -544.794117131
10601.2128384 49.782478266
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your x-coordinates are in the same as the y-coordinates for every data point. Thus, you're effectively telling matplotlib that you only have values on the diagonal in the x-y-plane.

One possible solution would be to simply transpose your y-coordinates. However, using numpy's `meshgrid` ([link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)) function is probably a lot more comfortable.

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(bins),np.arange(bins))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, matrix)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much

Edit: trying to vote for this answer, but it won't let me due to lack of points.  thanks again though!